# Apache: show error message in browser for 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: apache2, 500-error

When Apache shows 500 Internal Server Error page, there is no information about the error itself. It can be error in `.htaccess` or something different, but you'll never know until you look into `error.log`.

Is it possible to display error message immediately in the browser?

Comment: The target audience here generally does not want to display such messages in browser, as they could be security sensitive. For development, your programming framework may provide a solution, but we would not know about the specifics.

Comment: Sometimes recursive redirections and Apache misconfiguration result in a error 500 that is not the cause of any programming framework, and as such, can only be debugged with information that is only available on error.log. I think this question is useful for a development environment.

Comment: Try this: <?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1); ?> Tell us then how it was.

Comment: @DiegoGraziano I do not have mod_php in my Apache. In question I told about errors like ones from .htaccess, which occur before any programming language module in apache would get control.

Comment: Can we get an answer to this?  As a developer, I'm working with a Python framework that is highly volatile and throws unexpected errors during development.  I'd rather see Apache Error Log messages dumped straight to the browser in the development environment.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, there's no built-in way to tell Apache to simply dump error log messages directly to the browser. I'm betting the error_log output happens in an independent part of the Apache pipeline -- just a guess.

Most of the time when someone wants output errors directly to the browser, that person is a developer working in a web script such as PHP, Python, Perl, or other lang. In order to output error messages that occur within your lang interpretter, you have to format the output and pass it through apache as if it was normal output.

**PHP**

Some languages provide an easy way to do this, such as the well known error_reporting switch in PHP.

**Python**

Unfortunately some languages, make this painful or almost impossible and Python is one of them.

At one time this was apparently possible using https://docs.python.org/3/library/cgitb.html

However that library has been deprecated. Seems like the Python community doesn't have much love for developers who want to get immediate feedback about errors in the browser. :(